# How to align image - Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, alignment

I need to know how to align an image in Matlab for further work.

for example I have the next license plate image and I want to recognize all
the digits.

[image]

my program works for straight images so, I need to align the image and then 
preform the optical recognition system.

The method should be as much as universal that fits for all kinds of plates and in all kinds of angles.

**EDIT:** I tried to do this with Hough Transform but I didn't Succeed. anybody can help me do to this?

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if this were OpenCV i'd say find the most prominent nearly-horizontal Hough line, compute its angle, then do an affine transformation with a rotation matrix with the angle as previously calculated. Does this have any matlab equivalent? Then you might find it helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution was first hinted at by [@AruniRC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297353/arunirc) in the comments, then implemented by [@belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770818/how-to-align-image-matlab/6240992#6240992) in Mathematica. The following is my interpretation in MATLAB.

The idea is basically the same: detect edges using Canny method, find prominent lines using Hough Transform, compute line angles, finally perform a Shearing Transform to align the image.

```
%# read and crop image
I = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJHaA.png');
I = I(:,1:end-3,:);     %# remove small white band on the side

%# egde detection
BW = edge(rgb2gray(I), 'canny');

%# hough transform
[H T R] = hough(BW);
P  = houghpeaks(H, 4, 'threshold',ceil(0.75*max(H(:))));
lines = houghlines(BW, T, R, P);

%# shearing transforma
slopes = vertcat(lines.point2) - vertcat(lines.point1);
slopes = slopes(:,2) ./ slopes(:,1);
TFORM = maketform('affine', [1 -slopes(1) 0 ; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1]);
II = imtransform(I, TFORM);
```

Now lets see the results

```
%# show edges
figure, imshow(BW)

%# show accumlation matrix and peaks
figure, imshow(imadjust(mat2gray(H)), [], 'XData',T, 'YData',R, 'InitialMagnification','fit')
xlabel('\theta (degrees)'), ylabel('\rho'), colormap(hot), colorbar
hold on, plot(T(P(:,2)), R(P(:,1)), 'gs', 'LineWidth',2), hold off
axis on, axis normal

%# show image with lines overlayed, and the aligned/rotated image
figure
subplot(121), imshow(I), hold on
for k = 1:length(lines)
    xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
    plot(xy(:,1), xy(:,2), 'g.-', 'LineWidth',2);
end, hold off
subplot(122), imshow(II)
```

[image: canny_edges]
[image: hough_transform]
[image: lines_overlayed_image_aligned]

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thanks Amro. +1.

Answer (score 6):

In Mathematica, using Edge Detection and Hough Transform:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. do you know how to do that in Matlab? my Matlab skills isn't so good...

Comment: @Michael Sorry, no Matlab here. But you got the keywords: Hough Transform, Edge Detection, Shearing Transform.

Comment: @Michael, @belisarius: I posted a solution in MATLAB inspired by this one

Answer (score 3):

If you are using some kind of machine learning toolbox for text recognition, try to learn from ALL plates - not only aligned ones. Recognition results should be equally well if you transform the plate or dont, since by transforming, no new informations according to the true number will enhance the image.

Answer (score 0):

If all the images have a dark background like that one, you could binarize the image, fit lines to the top or bottom of the bright area and calculate an affine projection matrix from the line gradient.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm performing binarization to all the images so yes the background would be like this. how can I fit the lines?