# How can I rotate letters in a Captcha image with Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-rotation

I need to rotate the letters on the following Captcha by let's say : 25° for instance. I don't want to rotate all the image but every letter separately.

After reading the image I transform it to binary image :

```
BW1 = im2bw(I,map,0.4);  % keeps only white and black
```

But it's not necessary.

Here is the image : 
[image]

And here is want I want to get:

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean skewing the image?

Comment: I'm implementing a paper about breaking some types of Captchas. I did many transformation on the image (skeleton, joining the disjoined pats of the letters, hough transform, ...). At end I computed the average angle of the Hough lines. Now I need to rotate each letter by this computed angle. I think It won't change anything if I talk about all of the previous steps. Because their aims is only to find the angle which I need to rotate the letters with.

Comment: Yes CST-Link skewing the letters one by one.

Comment: Rotating each letter by a known angle won't undo the distortion.  There is extreme sheering experienced with each letter that simply rotating will keep the distortion intact.  You're going to need to do more than just rotating each character individually.

Comment: Actually I need to rotate only the vertical lines.

Comment: How do you define a "vertical" line in your skewed image if you have no reference?  However, this post may provide some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770818/how-to-align-image-matlab - You can apply this logic for each character individually.